# Check if a file exists. What's the diffence between `~/<directory>` and `/home/user/<directory>`

Tags: linux, shell

I have written an automation script to install kernel. This script needs to be able to run on different machines and hence it should be independent of the user. I want to check if the user has downloaded the .tar.gz file before I start the installation.

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="/home/csgurel/Downloads/auto_video.tar.gz"
file2="~/Downloads/auto_video.tar.gz"

function kernel_install() {
    if [ -f $file1 ] ; then
        echo "Kernel installation is started."
        # execute the installation functions here.
    else
        echo "The required file couldn't be located."
    fi
}

kernel_install
```

The problem is that when I use the absolute directory (i.e. file1) in the form of `/home/user/<directory>`, everything works fine and

> Kernel installation is started.

is printed but when I use the tilde symbol to make the directory independent of the user name in the form of `~/<directory>` (i.e. file2) it prints

> The required file couldn't be located.

How can I check if this file exists independent of the user name?

Comment: Why not just cd to '~/Downloads' instead of putting it in the file name and then just check for the file in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's from [ShellCheck's wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2088):

### Tilde does not expand in quotes. Use $HOME.

#### Problematic code:

```sh
rm "~/Desktop/$filename"
```

#### Correct code:

```sh
rm "$HOME/Desktop/$filename"
```

#### Rationale:

Tilde does not expand to the user's home directory when it's single or double quoted. Use double quotes and `$HOME` instead.

Alternatively, the `~/` can be left unquoted, as in `rm ~/"Desktop/$filename"`.

Comment: I actually knew this but I had forgotten.